# Updating Android material version causes Firebase tests to fail for but still passes locally

Tags: android, firebase, android-espresso, android-testing, firebase-test-lab

Recently I updated `com.google.android.material:material` from `1.4.0` to `1.9.0` and noticed FTL tests on `TextInputLayout` with `MaterialAutoCompleteTextView` started to fail consistently.

After some version elimination, it happens between the transition from `1.5.0` -> `1.6.0-alpha01`. Looking at the [changelogs](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases/tag/1.6.0-alpha01) nothing really jumped out as the source of failure for FTL.

The test on FTL fails when it's trying to click on the `TextInputLayout` and verifying `ExposedDropdownMenu` child's text. From the video on FTL the test seems to hang and no drop down appears.

This passes locally, and passes on FTL on version `1.5.0` or lower.

```
onView(withId(R.id.textInputLayout)).perform(scrollTo(), click())
onView(withText("Dropdown Name")).inRoot(isPlatformPopup()).perform(click())
```

The failure on FTL is

```
 androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingRootException: Matcher 'with decor view of type PopupWindow$PopupViewContainer' did not match any of the following roots: [Root{application-window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@ed50a71, window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@ed50a71, has-window-focus=true, layout-params-type=1, layout-params-string={(0,0)(fillxfill) ty=BASE_APPLICATION wanim=0x10302fe
```

The layout is pretty standard

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:errorEnabled="false">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="none"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Any suggestions or explanations??